# How to install gtk+2.0

Tags: 14.04, gtk-2

When I enter the command

```
sudo apt-get install gtk+2.0
```

I get Output is like this:

```
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'gir1.2-spice-client-gtk-2.0' for regex 'gtk+-2.0'
Note, selecting 'gir1.2-gtk-2.0' for regex 'gtk+-2.0'
Note, selecting 'libspice-client-gtk-2.0-dev' for regex 'gtk+-2.0'
Note, selecting 'libspice-client-gtk-2.0-1' for regex 'gtk+-2.0'
Note, selecting 'gir1.0-gtk-2.0' for regex 'gtk+-2.0'
gir1.2-gtk-2.0 is already the newest version.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libspice-client-gtk-2.0-dev : Depends: libgtk2.0-dev (>= 2.18.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I am new to Ubuntu what I have to do?

Comment: I don't think there is a package named `gtk+2.0` - what package are you trying to install, exactly, and why? (unfortunately `apt-get` insists on treating package names as regexes when it doesn't find an exact match)

Comment: I have to install a software named lamps for data analysis purpose. For it installation they need The graphics environment gtk+ (example: gtk+-1.2.10-33). so what i have to do

Comment: If you have Ubuntu, you already have a GTK-based graphic environment.

Comment: but when i am make my software they showing                                                                           gcc -g `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0`   -c -o ascii2d.o ascii2d.c
Package gtk+-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtk+-2.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gtk+-2.0' found
ascii2d.c:1:21: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [ascii2d.o] Error 1
so what i am supposed to do

Comment: If you're trying to **build** software that requires `gtk+-2.0` then the package you should install is called `libgtk2.0-dev`. Make sure you run `sudo apt-get update` first to make sure the package catalog is up to date.

Comment: but when I am trying to install libgtk2.0 after update they shows,                             
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgtk2.0-dev : Depends: libpango1.0-dev (>= 1.20) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libcairo2-dev (>= 1.6.4-6.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Answer (score 43):

The right command is:

```
sudo apt-get install gtk2.0
```

Answer (score 28):

First you need gtk2 and the command for that is

```
sudo apt-get install gtk2.0
```

chances are that its already installed.

Then you need the development package libgtk2.0-dev and this can be installed by the command:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libgtk2.0-dev
```

Comment: I tried to install gtk2.0 in Ubuntu-bash (Windows 10) I got following error after running  the first comment. Errors were encountered while processing:
 libpython3.5-minimal:amd64
 python3.5-minimal
 libpython3.5-stdlib:amd64
 python3.5
 libpython3.5:amd64
 libpython3.5-dev:amd64
 libpython3-dev:amd64
 python3.5-dev
 python3-dev
 python3-pip
 python3-setuptools
 python3-wheel
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Are you trying install within a Linux Subsystem on Windows 10? My tested solution is only for a real Ubuntu system installed on its own partition. I have not tested on a Windows Linux subsystem and I cannot recommend its use. Serious users should install Ubuntu on its own partition.